# Zoom to a specific D3 path in a map without clicking

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created an interactive map. Let's now say someone has send you a link like this one: [**Arda Maps - Isle of Balar**](http://arda-maps.org/ages/first/#IsleOfBalar) as example.

This is a direct link that creates a mark on the specific isle as you can see. Additionally I would like to zoom to the isle or let's say the mark. But until now I did not find a good solution, beside click invoking.

I found [Mbostock 2206590](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590) which is the way of zooming I would like to have. But as the title says I **don't want to click** the area/mark or invoke a click. I would like to zoom in directly when you come with the URL.

So maybe how can I do it the following way:

```
d3.select('.maptimeline-IsleOfBalar').call(function(d) {
    // zoom to the d
});
```

The problem is that I need the object but in this way I just get an array. On a click event it's very easy to get the object for sure.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Can you not identify what you want to zoom in on?

Comment: You might need to reload if you don't see the red pointer on the Isle of Balar. If you see it: I want to center the map on the isle and also zoom in, let's say 20x on the isle. That's all I want =)

Comment: So just get the data associated with that and call the `click` function in the example with it.

Comment: So setting the click event on the marker is the *only* way to go?

Comment: No, you can call whatever code you're calling when the marker is clicked in other contexts, e.g. when the page is loaded.

Comment: Could you post the code for this?

Comment: It's the implementation of the `click` function in the example. All you need to do is pass the data for the feature you want to zoom in on (not on click, on page load).

Comment: Exactly, but I have no idea how to pass the d3 class array as object to that function.

Comment: The argument is the data bound to the specific element, which you have access to because you're binding it to the elements in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was to **create a custom click function**. First of all the way to use it is:

```
$(".maptimeline-"+classtext).d3Click();
```

and the d3Click finally looks like:

```
jQuery.fn.d3Click = function () {
    this.each(function (i, e) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        e.dispatchEvent(evt);
    });
};
```

This will create the fake-click on the specific element. And as you can see here: **http://arda-maps.org/ages/first/#IsleOfBalar** it actually works pretty well.